# Type Hinting in PhpStorm of Object extending ArrayObject

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7

I would like to enable type hinting in PhpStorm for `ArrayObject` classes

My ArrayObject looks like this:

```
class MyArrayObject extends ArrayObject
{
     public function __construct()
     {
          $this['value1'] = new Class1();
          $this['value2'] = new Class1();             

     }
}
```

And I use it like

```
$MyObject = new MyArrayObject();

$MyObject['value1']->methodInClass1(); // methodInClass1 is not Hinted in PhpStorm.
```

I tried different approaches like to override an `offsetGet()` from the ArrayObject and to put `@return` on it but it doesn't work.

```
/** @return Class1 */
public function offsetGet($index) {
    return parent::offsetGet($index);
}
```

Is it possible at all to Type Hint the ArrayObject in PhpStorm?

Comment: Actually, I've just tried the `@return` tag on `offsetGet` and it does work on my end (same for the explicit return type). What PhpStorm version are you running?

Comment: The version is 2020.2.2 ..Using Symfony Framework. The MyArrayObject is a symfony service but I think this is not relevant.

Comment: Actually, I'm using EAP right now, so this might be an upcoming feature. Would `/** @var Class1[] $MyObject */` right above your variable be ok in the meantime?

Comment: I'm on 2020.2.3, one point newer. I'm not getting any errors from PhpStorm, but I'm also not getting autocomplete or got to definition options.

Comment: With PhpStorm 2020.3 you will be able to use PHP8 attributes _(including `#[ArrayShape]`)_ and it's backward compatible with PHP7 since `#` is also (by default) a comment in PHP.  [PhpStorm blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/10/phpstorm-2020-3-eap-4/)

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier, although that is true, since we already have docblock annotations I don't know if that will help any more

Comment: Looks like [it's supposed to have been working for 6 years](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-8039). I'm guessing something broke in between and they fixed it again, because it's working fine on last EAP.